# Why does negative z-index and non-static position disable my checkbox in most browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing a checkbox. At certain times the `z-index` of this div is negative and the postition `relative` and when this is the case the checkbox is not reachable in the latest versions of Chrome, FF, Safari or Opera. The checkbox is reachable in IE9, however. The same goes for `absolute` and `fixed` whilst `static` works.

I have been trying to find the reasons behind this but to no avail.

Can I assume that the non-IE-browsers handles this situation correct and IE does not?

An example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.divWithCheckboxRelativePos{
    position: relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
.divWithCheckboxStaticPos{
    position:static;
    z-index:-1;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="divWithCheckboxRelativePos">
    Does not work:<input type="checkbox" onclick="alert(this.checked);"/>
</div>
<div class="divWithCheckboxStaticPos">
    Works:<input type="checkbox" onclick="alert(this.checked);"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I usually avoid using negative z-index values - is there a reason that you need them to be negative?

Comment: I will have to make some structural changes but certainly I can work around this. Mostly I am curious as to why this behaviour seems to be standard and why IE9 deviates from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason `static` works is because `z-index` is only applied to positioned elements - `absolute`, `relative`, `fixed`.

I believe in this instance, IE may have got the `z-index` right. The problem you are describing sounds like the `checkbox` is being placed behind the parent element in Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera.

The following text extract from [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) descibes the order in which the z-index elements are drawn:

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

However, it sounds like Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera could be drawing the negative z-index elements (2) before the parent element's background (1).

In any case, as you can see, the negative `z-index` elements are pretty near the bottom of the pile, so if an element requires any kind of user interaction then a negative `z-index` is probably not the best choice.

**Additional Note**

Another reason it could be working in IE and not the others is that IE tends to treat "empty" elements as if they do not exist. So if there is something drawn above the `checkbox` but it contains nothing (no background, content etc) then IE will ignore it and allow interaction with the element below - where the other browsers will not.

Comment: I'd say put background:rgba(255,255,255.8) to parent container to see if checkbox is behind

Comment: I changed the background of the parent div but the checkbox is still visible (yet not available). I have worked around this issue now and I understand that static does not work with z-index. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @ahdaniels No problem - there must be something else drawn above them in the other browsers. If I can work out what it is then I will add it to this answer.