# Facebook send button dialog z-index issue

Tags: html, css, facebook, z-index

How do I fix the following issue:

[image: Facebook z-index issue]

I've tried setting the z-index of my images to -1 but on IE and opera they go behind the rgba background of their container:

[image]

You can see the following problem here (in IE and Opera):

http://dump.ly/LVWY1v6oCPX9

Comment: You are in the matrix now - we can see the pictures just by looking at the code...but we can't see code just by looking at pictures

Comment: heh all the code you need is a right click->inspect element away!

Comment: Ok, in that case I am missing something. Is that link not just to pictures? Also, you might find the answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9110286/681807) useful. It is why to avoid negative z-indexes. Is there a reason you need to use them?

Comment: * click * sorry, I get it now - your site just looked to professional - I thought you were linking us to a site where your images were located :p

Comment: I use a negative z-index because I cant seem to control the z-index of the Facebook dialog, I need to ensure that it pops up over the top of my images and the only way I've found so far is to set the z-index of the images to < 0...

Comment: Ok - unfortunately the site doesn't work for me at all in IE9. The part where the images are supposed to be does not seem to exist.

Comment: Hmm actually yes I noticed that it only seems to load properly in IE9 when I had the debugger open (F12), thats another IE bug needs investigating ;) sigh!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7419/discussion-between-cjroebuck-and-my-head-hurts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using negative `z-index` values as these elements are one of the first things to be drawn when a browser builds a page (more information can be found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9112028/681807)) - which means that elements can appear behind things you might not expect (in-flow elements etc).

To ensure the facebook dropdown is always above the images you can apply a larger `z-index` to the facebook parent element - in this case `#dump_options` - than the one containing the images - in this case `.preview`.

So your CSS could be:

```
#dump_options {
    ...
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    ...
}

.preview {
    ...
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If setting the z-index of the parent doesn't do it, try setting the z-index of the parent's parent and so on. Remember z-indices can be nested.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the CSS to this :

```
*Images Class*{
   opacity:0.4;
   filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

[Link, W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)

Comment: Thats the problem right there, the images are behind the semi-transparent black background. Compare the same in Chrome and you will see the difference..

Comment: The only difference is that the IE email has no drop shadow. But I still don't see a difference between IE, Chrome and Opera.

Comment: If you look at the images in IE/Opera, they are very dark compared to chrome. I will post an image of the difference..

Comment: No thats not the issue, the negative z-index is forcing the images behind the black background of their container, so really I need to fix the z-index issue to get the images to be on top and then the FB dialog on top again

Comment: Ah okay. I don't know how to fix that problem... Sorry.