# Trying to select content of div with mouse(highlight text) that has a lower z-index

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an effect where the user scrolls down the page and as the user scrolls a section appears to be fixed to the background. The user keep on scrolling the rest of the content over that section which is fixed. I got that done but the problem is that I cant select text and I'm assuming the user wont be able to click any buttons. I think the problem is the z index. It wont let me select(highlight) the text because there is a layer in front of it?

I used `position:relative; top : 100vh` to push the lower content down. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yg8jdm4p/)

```
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .first, .second, .third, .fourth, .fith{
        height: 100vh;
        background: pink;
    }
    .sixth{
        height: 100vh;
        background: green;
    }
    .seventh{
        height: 50vh;
        background: hotpink;
    }
    .fith{
        z-index: -3;
        background: red;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .box{
        background: blue;
        width: 300px;
        height: 400px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 10%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .above{
        position: relative;
        top:100vh;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="first">
</div>
<div class="second">secnd</div>
<div class="third">third</div>
<div class="fourth">4 fourth</div>
<div class="fith">
    fith
    <div class="box">

    </div>
    <div class="box">
        gsrgsegg
    </div>
    <div class="box">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="above">
    <div class="sixth">6</div>
    <div class="seventh">7even</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yg8jdm4p/6/)

The problem is that z-index was negative, here's a fix:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.first, .second, .third, .fourth, .fith{
    height: 100vh;
    background: pink;
    z-index:2;           // Add z-index for all classes
    position: relative; // Add position relative
}
.sixth{
    height: 100vh;
    background: green;
}
.seventh{
    height: 50vh;
    background: hotpink;
}
.fith{
    z-index: 0; // z-inde : Zero
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.box{
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.above{
    position: relative;
    top:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This has the effect I want. I just learnt something new. I tested to see if z-index: -1 would work and it didn't. I just thought that the relative value of the z-indexes is what mattered but I see you cant put a negative. or is is it if you want to select the text element you cant put a negative z-index? because I think you could use  negative and positive  z-indexes for layering content .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110286/why-does-negative-z-index-and-non-static-position-disable-my-checkbox-in-most-br