# How do I move content of one div over another using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code :

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="first_div">
      <div class="nested_first">
      </div>
      <div class="nested_second">
          Hello World
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
.main{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
.nested_first {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.nested_second {
  width: 32.5rem;
  border: 3px solid $white;
  height: 100%;
}

.first_div {
  position: relative;
  height: 7rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .3rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    .planTitle {
      color: $forest;
    }
    .planChannels {
      color: black;
    }
  }
}
```

Because of this, I can't see the content of nested_second. How can I make it visible just using HTML and CSS.

The pen of this code is as follows :
[code](http://codepen.io/ajaygaur319/pen/oLgOyp)

Comment: give a `position: absolute` or  `position: relative` to `.nested_second`

Comment: @twxia it worked for me but I don't know the reason. If you please elaborate then it would be handy. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @ajay-gaur :D  , How it render like this? The spec describe the order of rendering : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index or http://stackoverflow.com/a/9112028/2016836

Comment: The `position: static` will always behind the non-static position if they are in same root stack :D

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to pass the second one over the first, you could use the z-index property : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: In this case, try adding a position:relative on the second one (which must have a z-index superior than the first)